# Return column headers (columns B onwards) based on a text value in Column A and number value in other columns - in a Google spreadsheet

Tags: matrix, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

I have a matrix - 1,172 words down column A, then the same 1,172 names across row 1. Then each word is cross-referenced with all the other names to give a similarity score (this is already done).

In another sheet, I want to look up a word, and return all the words with which it has a certain similarity score - in this case, greater than or equal to 0.33. I attach a MWE, in which I give an idea of the answer I am looking for by looking it up manually.

I think it's some sort of reverse lookup. As in, instead of finding the value corresponding to a particular row and a particular column, it's finding the column based on value in the main sheet and row. I'm just really stuck at this point and would massively appreciate some help. Thanks! [MWE here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JnZEIedHDCVLApva-2T95IbxEEF2eGUT0gh4GX3R_2U/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your words on the second sheet are in the same order then:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(Scores!B$1:W$1,(Scores!B2:W2>=0.33)*((Scores!B2:W2<1)))),"-")
```

Drag down.

#### Explanation:

- Filter the values from row 1 according to the similarity score condition, using [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en).
- Concatenate the filtered values using [TEXTJOIN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7013992?hl=en).